# why can't I change an important z-index with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html

```
<div id="mydiv">HEllo</div>
```

the following css

```
#mydiv {
    z-index: 9999 !important;

}
```

using jquery 1.11.0

with this code

```
console.log(jQuery("#mydiv").css("z-index"));
jQuery("#mydiv").css({'z-index':'3000 !important'});

console.log(jQuery("#mydiv").css("z-index"));
```

why does it print 9999 twice?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsr5h16z/)

Comment: try `jQuery("div#mydiv").css({'z-index':'3000 !important'});`

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this in document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  console.log(jQuery("#mydiv").css("z-index"));
  jQuery("#mydiv").css({'z-index':'3000 !important'});

  console.log(jQuery("#mydiv").css("z-index"));
});
```